# Django redirect interrupted by browser?

Tags: django, google-chrome, firefox, redirect, browser

I have a very simple view that is purposed to track a user's click and redirect them to an external page:

```
def redirect_view(request, uu_id):
    my_model = MyModel.objects.get(uuid = uu_id)
    my_model.clicked_link = True
    my_model.save()
    return redirect('https://www.some-other-site.com')
```

For about half of the users that interact with this view it works perfectly! Our logs show a 302 response and then nothing further from the user.

For the other half of our users they are strangely redirected to the base url of our site in http, then because we have `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True` they are redirected to https, and finally because they are not authenticated they are redirected for authentication.

Our logs for this type of user look something like this:

```
Feb 21 10:04:51 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/redirect-url" host=mysite.com request_id=123 fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=302 bytes=268 protocol=https 
Feb 21 10:04:51 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysite.com request_id=456 fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=301 bytes=262 protocol=http 
Feb 21 10:04:52 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/" host=mysite.com request_id=789 fwd="..." dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=302 bytes=360 protocol=https
```

There is nothing in our code that would suggest a redirect to our base url so my only thought is that they have some sort of browser setting that limits external redirects.

Could this in any way be caused by Django?
If this is not a Django issue what is causing it? and what would be a good work-around?

Comment: I don't know of a browser setting that would explain what you report. How do you know that the scenario you think is happening is the actual one? Have users filed reports that correspond to what you see in the log? If you or your colleagues interpreted what was happening *solely* from looking at the logs, you may have misinterpreted what is going on.

Comment: @Louis This is all interpretation. Do you have any idea of what else could cause this?

Comment: I would try to raise an exception inside redirect_view() to see what happens. If the consequences are exactly the behaviour you describe, then you can focus your attention to MyModel.objects.get() and my_model.save(). I'm sure Django doesn't take any action by it's own

Comment: @MarioOrlandi on our end we can see that the model gets updated so get() and save() both work successfully, is that what you are describing?

Comment: Uhh I see ... in that case my guess is wrong. As a matter of investigation, I would nonetheless throw an exception from the view. The user is redirected to error page 500. What happens next ?

Comment: Is it possible this could be caused by the website you are redirecting your users to? Maybe they have a functinality like, when certain conditions meet, they redirect requests back to the originating host?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali That is an interesting idea, but on my computer I am able to successfully follow the redirects and unable to reproduce the issue

Comment: @grrrrrr I thought similarly to OzgurAkcali. Though I'm not convinced that's the most *likely* cause. Another thing that may be happening is that some users have a setting or extension that  causes their browser to perform a query on the front page of your site *irrespective* of the redirect. They're not redirected back to your site but there's *another* query being performed around the same time they are redirected to the other site. That's why I asked whether you had users complaining that they are redirected back. Just going by the logs, it is easy to infer connections that don't exist.

Comment: @Louis, thanks for taking the time to follow up. I was able to get one of the users on the phone yesterday and got more info. The view in question and others where I am seeing similar behavior is accessed via a link sent in an email. The user I spoke with claimed he did not click the link when we saw the strange redirect since he does not work on Sundays, but says they do have an intense email scanner. I have set up some additional logging to see the user agent when these views are accessed which I think could help find exactly what is going on...

Comment: Is there any Javascript in your templates concerning this??

Comment: @PwnSauceDesigns this view flow does not have any templates involved

Comment: @grrrrrr Can you please shor the urlpatterns?